# Does this part of a vintage font have a name?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am looking for vintage style fonts with this chevron element through it, I've noticed it on a few fonts, Does this element have a name in typography terms?

(This particular font is called "Nuevo vintage font")

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are called **Spurs**.

> They're most closely associated with Western Type but they first appeared in a very different location: France! "By the end of the seventeenth century... gone are the irrelevancies of calligraphy, replaced instead by the spurs, beaks, serifs and terminals of modern typography. ...when a committee of French academics was convened to study the formation of the perfect roman letter." "Louis XIV incorporated this committee into the Académie des Sciences, the council he organized for the staggering undertaking of recording for posterity an account of all the realms of human endeavor, the first of these engravings became the conceptual basis for a new series of types made for the exclusive use of the crown: cut by Phillipe Grandjean beginning in 1694, these are the romains du roi, the King’s romans."

Quoted from [kelseyanneart.com](http://kelseyanneart.com/blog/2018/9/1/answered-in-lettering-whats-a-spur-and-how-do-you-use-it)

<sub>(I have no affiliation with the link. It is merely provided for additional information.)</sub>